# Jquery How to read custom attribute value

Tags: jquery

i gave one dropdown and it has one custom attributed i added called `ShipTo`. now my dropdown html looks like

```
<select id="ddlCountry" runat="server" style="width: 300px; font-size: 9pt; float:left; margin-top: 3px;">
<option shipto=''  value="">Select your location</option>
<option shipto='GBR'  value="gb_en_home">United Kingdom - English</option>
<option shipto='USA'  value="us_en_home">United States - English</option>
</select>
```

this way i try to read custom attribute value

```
var ShipTo = $("#ddlCountry").attr("shipto");
alert(ShipTo );
```

but the above code does not work. so can anyone guide me how to achieve it. thanks

### EDIT

i figured out how to read that custom attribute data

```
var ShipTo = $("#ddlCountry").find('option:selected').attr("shipto");
```

the above code works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to get the attribute from select, you need to get it from the option like this

```
$('#ddlCountry option:selected').attr('shipto');
```

Use [**`:selected`**](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) to get the selected option.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2w386uff/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The dropdown `#ddlCountry` doesn't have custom attribute. You should target the `<option>` instead:

```
var ShipTo = $("#ddlCountry option:selected").attr("shipto");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try. Getting value of selected `option`

```
$('#ddlCountry option:selected').attr('shipto');
```

## [Wroking DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/49yeczkL/)

Answer (score 1):

you should use data attributes instead

```
<select id="ddlCountry" runat="server" style="width: 300px; font-size: 9pt; float:left; margin-top: 3px;">
    <option data-shipto=''  value="">Select your location</option>
    <option data-shipto='GBR'  value="gb_en_home">United Kingdom - English</option>
    <option data-shipto='USA'  value="us_en_home">United States - English</option>
</select>
```

and you access it like

```
var ShipTo = $("#ddlCountry option:selected").data("shipto");
alert(ShipTo );
```